# Pydev multiline parenthesis import not working

Tags: pydev

In Pydev I select,

```
How to break import in multiline?
1) Use escape character 
2) Use parenthesis
```

I select option 2). Still, when I import modules, they are broken with a backslash.

Using backslash is against my company's coding policy. How can I tell PyDev to use parenthesis instead?

Option 1) -- WRONG format

```
from mymodule import a,\
    b, c
```

Option 2) -- RIGHT format

```
from mymodule import (
    a,
    b,
    c
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, PyDev will use `\` as the separator unless you've previously added `(` to the import.

Workarounds are:

Use `isort` as the sort engine for imports and turn on `sort on save` so that on save things become correct.

Use the `black` formatter which will also formats imports (and then turn on format on save).

You can create an issue at the PyDev tracker for this: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/ -- but I'm not sure when I'll be able to fix it... pull requests are welcome ;)